# Syntax error with php password_hash

Tags: php, hash

I'm taking this straight from the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), but I'm still getting a syntax error. Here is the code. It's the first line that is causing the error.

```
$options = [
  'cost' => 12,
];
$hash = password_hash('$plaintext', PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options)."\n";
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

I'm pretty new to php, and am not familiar with this array syntax, so I'm having difficult trouble shooting it. What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Your version of PHP doesn't support the shorthand array syntax.

Comment: http://3v4l.org/KWK0e explains it

Comment: Why do I get a -1 for this? It's a legitimate question. Geez.

Comment: Thanks, man! Right back atcha!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using an older version of PHP. Can you execute this code:

```
<?php
 echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion();
```

If it's not 5.5, then the second function won't work. The error you are getting is with your first line, which is avaiable since PHP 5.4(?). The code is otherwise valid.

Comment: Thanks. You're right. My server is only on 5.3.6. That sucks. I can't find an easily implementable bcrypt library.

Comment: @usr55410 - Use the array syntax Brad mentioned, together with PHP's [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php).

Answer (score 4):

You want this instead:

```
$options = array(
  'cost' => 12
);
```

The array syntax used in the documentation is for PHP 5.5.  So is `password_hash()`.

Also, I suspect that instead of `'$plaintext'`, you want just `$plaintext`.  Unless you want all your passwords to literally be "$plaintext".

Answer (score 1):

You're using the short array syntax, which replaces array() with []. It works only on only PHP 5.4 >

So, instead of:

```
$options = [
  'cost' => 12,
];
```

You want:

```
$options = array(
  'cost' => 12,
);
```

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php (see example #1)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The code must be if `$options` is an array

```
$options = array(
  'cost' => 12,
);
$hash = password_hash('$plaintext', PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options)."\n";
```